# sed and perl not replacing a letter in a file

Tags: perl, sed

I have a file 1.htm. I want to replace a letter ṣ (s with dot below). I tried with both sed and perl and it does not replace.

```
sed -i 's/ṣ/s/g' "1.htm"
perl -i -pe 's/ṣ/s/g' "1.htm"
```

can anyone suggest what to do

[1.html](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ji9bbezfg9fd744/unreplacable_126.htm) (not replacing ṣ)

Also i have found another strange thing. Sed (same command as above) replaces in one file but not the other I am putting the links

[replacable.html](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ji9bbezfg9fd744/unreplacable_126.htm)

[unreplacable.html](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ji9bbezfg9fd744/unreplacable_126.htm) same as 1.html

Why is it happening so. sed is able to replace ṣ in one file but not the other.

Comment: when i open in kate editor and find ṣ, it finds. But sed and perl are not able to replace. I have many such files to replace.

Comment: I cannot see such character in the file. None. Are you sure it didn't work?

Comment: What is the encoding of your file? utf8? ascii? utf16? In worst case, once you find out the encoding you can always use s/\oXXX/whatever, meaning replace the octal constant with 'whatever'.

Comment: You have combined characters, that is, a "s" followed with a " ̣".

Comment: i found that in replaceble.htm file ṣ (U+1E63 LATIN SMALL LETTER S WITH DOT BELOW) is one single letter thats why it gets replaced with sed. but in unreplaceble.htm file ṣ is s followed by the Unicode character U+0323 are different. I understood

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have combined characters in the html file. That is, the `"ṣ"` is really a `"s"` followed by a `" ̣"` (a COMBINING DOT BELOW). One possibility to fix the oneliner is:

```
perl -C -i -pe 's/s\x{0323}/s/g' "1.htm"
```

That is, turn utf8 mode for stdout/stdin on (`-C`) and explicitely write the two characters in the left side of the `s///`.

Another possibility is to normalize all the combining characters using `Unicode::Normalize`, e.g.:

```
perl -C -MUnicode::Normalize -Mutf8 -i -pe '$_=NFKC($_); s/ṣ/s/g' "1.htm"
```

But this would also normalize all the other characters in the input file, which may or may not be OK for you.

Comment: thank you, the first command worked. Also is it possible to use sed command also. Can you tell what is the encoding of my file and how to find it. How did you found that s and dot are two characters, because when we open in vi or kate editor its not obvious. But when i open the file in html and by firebug saw the html code it shows s#&803. So where did you find 0323 number from.

Comment: i want to use by sed some thing like this
find . -name "*.html" -exec sed -i.bak 'y/ŚśḌḍḤḥḶḷṀṁṄṅṆṇṚṛṜṝṢṣṬṭl̐/SsDdHhLlMmNnNnRrRrSsTtl/' {} \;

Comment: I used emacs in X11 mode to look at the file, and my emacs does not combine the characters automatically, so I saw the "s" and then the dot below. Why do you want to have a sed solution? You can use a perl oneliner together with find, too.

Comment: Sorry i dont have emacs. Because i checked in both kate and vim it shows as single letter. I want to use sed because as i have mentioned above i can use in a short format with find and also does multiple replacements using y. Because i dont want to replace all the diacratics.

Comment: As I already said, you can use perl instead of sed within the `find` command. Perl also has `y` (more commonly known as `tr`). But `tr` or `y` does not work here anyway because you have two characters to replace, so you have to use `s`.

Comment: Anyway, I think the original question is answered. If you have further questions how to use regular expressions with perl, or what's the best editor to deal with Unicode stuff, then this should probably go into new questions.

Comment: I had some more thing added to my question. I just edited it. I want to know the difference between the files.

Comment: What should i do about the other part of my question. Should i post as new topic

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\o341\o271\o243/s/g' file
```

To find seds octal interpretation of a character use:

```
echo 'ṣ'| sed l
```

This returns (for me):

```
\341\271\243$
ṣ
```

Then use `\onnn` (or combinations of) to find the correct pattern in the lefthandside (LFH) of the substitute command.

N.B. `\onnn` may also be used in the RHS of the substitute command.